# Choose classic cloud service VM size according deployment region

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-cloud-services

I'm deploying classic cloud service in different regions using ARM templates, till now was using same VM type(Standard_D2_v2) for all deployments, but found out that this VM is not available in all regions where I'm going to deploy. What are options to choose VM type according deployment region?

Answer (score 0):

Some regions do not have those available sizes. Can you change the VM sizes to the below

Standard_B1ls1. You might also have to check the cost if you using Micorosoft Azure

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue for that size in that region you are trying to deploy or it may not be available for you. So, you might be getting this error:

```
The operation '{Operation ID}' failed: 'The requested VM tier is currently not available in Region ({Region ID}) for this subscription. Please try another tier or deploy to a different location.'.
```

To Check the sizes available for your subscription in that region you can use azure Powershell or azure CLI with the below commands :

- `az vm list-skus --location southcentralus --output table` -- Azure CLI
- `Get-AzComputeResourceSku | where {$_.Locations -icontains "centralus"}` -- Azure Powershell

After getting the output if in restriction you find **NotAvailableForSubscription** means you cannot use that vm size.

Comment: you can refer this for more details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-troubleshoot-location-not-found-for-role-size